# Order by Clause conflicts with distinct in Excel VBA?

Tags: sql, excel

I can't figure out how to get past this error. I've seen how to do it when selecting one field, but not more than one. Can any SQL guru's out there give advice?

```
SELECT [Tool Name], MAX([Tool Start Time]) AS [Last Run]
FROM [Sheet1$]
GROUP BY [Tool Name]
ORDER BY [Tool Start Time] DESC
```

The first three lines work, but when trying to order the dates, I get the error.

Comment: There's no need for a distinct when grouping

Comment: edited, although it didn't make a difference

Comment: Try `ORDER BY [Last Run] desc`

Comment: or `ORDER BY MAX([Tool Start Time]) desc`

Comment: Awesome! You're second suggestion worked. Thanks